# How to make the content in this div in one line?

Tags: html

```
<div class = "form" >
  <div class = "row" >
    <label >Valid Check:</label >
    <div class = "input" >
    <span class = "input_wrapper" >
      <input type = "text" >
    </span >
    <span class = "systemMessage" id = "pos" >
      <img height = "10" src = "images/positive.gif" width = "12" />
      <p>This message is positive</p>
    </span >
    </div >
  </div >
</div >
```

I want these contents to get in line but any edits to display in the css that I do is not working. the problem is mainly with .systemMessage, it shows up in the next line under input. Below is a screenshot for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
margin-left: 3%
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <head>
      <title>Bright!</title>
   </head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <body bgcolor='#303030'link=" #ffbd59" vlink=" #ffbd59" alink=" #ffbd59">
      <div class = "form" >
         <div class = "row" >
            <label>Valid Check:</label >
            <div style="display: flex;" class = "input" >
               <span class = "input_wrapper" >
               <input type = "text" >
               </span >
               <span style="display: flex;" class = "systemMessage" id = "pos" >
                  <img height = "10" src = "images/positive.gif" width = "12" />
                  <p> This message is positive</p>
               </span >
            </div >
         </div >
      </div >
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JosephMenezes try this as above

Answer (score -1):

Use display:inline to show contents in one line

```
<div style="display:inline">
```